# Active Record Relation for Assigned and Created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise

I currently have a working Active Record association but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing something like this. Basically I have a model called Task. A task has one creator and can be assigned to many people. The user model is a Devise Model called User. This is my current setup but I don't like the query I need to use to fetch all Tasks for a user whether they created them or were assigned to them. Here are my models. My current setup is also terrible with pagination. Any suggestions?

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: 'creator_id', class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: 'Task'
  has_many :created_tasks, foreign_key: 'creator_id', class_name: 'Task'

  def tasks
    (assigned_tasks.includes(project: [:client]) + created_tasks.includes(project: [:client])).uniq
  end
end
```

So basicslly a Task has to have:

- One creator (User)
- Many Users assigned to it

**Solution**

```
  def tasks
    Task.joins('LEFT JOIN tasks_users ON tasks_users.task_id = tasks.id').where('tasks_users.user_id = :user_id OR tasks.creator_id = :user_id', { user_id: id }).includes(project: [:client])
  end
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more insight about what exactly you don't like about the method being used to fetch all tasks belonging to and assigned to the user? What particular issues do you have with it? Does it take too long? Create too many queries?

Comment: @Kyril Yes, sorry for not being more detailed, basically it gets tricky when I want to paginate this with Kaminari because its calling two separate tables (joins and actual tasks table) and it gets messy when I want to get all tasks with the `status: :open` which is an `enum` on the task.

Comment: Maybe get rid of the HABTM join and use a real model to join users to tasks called `Asssignment` or similar, `has_many :tasks, through :assignments`.

Comment: @Kris that could work but I need to get both assigned tasks and created task in one query so I can paginate it!

Comment: Could your task be assiged to multiple users or only one?

Comment: @oreoluwa multiple

Comment: Wouldn't this help with one query... Just query the new model to get all a users assigned and created tasks. You'll know if the user created the task if you store a `created_by_id` on the `Task`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to do this is:

```
class User
  def associated_tasks
    Task.joins(:user).joins("LEFT JOIN user_tasks ON user_tasks.task_id = tasks.id").where("users.id = :user_id OR user_tasks.user_id = :user_id", { user_id: id }).includes(project: [:client])
  end
end
```

Note that we're `LEFT JOIN`ing the join table between tasks and users, I called that `user_tasks`, you should be able to substitute for others.

There are other ways of doing this; I'd update the answer to include these, when I have some time.

Comment: I updated my question with your answer towards the bottom and I modified it slightly to fit inside an association method. Any idea why only the created tasks are being returned and non of the assigned tasks?

Comment: Nope it wouldn't work inside a `has_many`, because it assumes the relationship has been created already. Use `scope :assigned_tasks, -> (user){ the methods here }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complicating it in this way, I would just put a created_by column in the task table

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks

  def user_created_tasks
    tasks.select { |x| x.created_by == id }
  end
end
```

Or something like that to find the tasks by user

Comment: I'm sure you don't want to try this with `ActiveRecord`. This would fetch all the records and start the selection in memory. It would be worse than that specified by the `OP`.

Comment: @oreoluwa and this is where my downfall is, I can't seem to come up with a query that is both efficient and easy to filter.

Comment: trying to mock a query that might help with this, it may use Arel though, if you don't mind?

Comment: Arel is used by `ActiveRecord` internally

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` accepts a where clause which you can use to further scope the relation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: 'Task'
  has_many :created_tasks, foreign_key: 'creator_id', class_name: 'Task'
  has_many :tasks, ->(user) { joins(:users).where('users.id = ? OR tasks.creator_id = ?', user.id, user.id) }
end
```

..and then `@user.tasks` should provide you with all tasks assigned and created by the given user.

Comment: Will this work with the joins table as well used by `has_and_belongs_to_many :assigned_tasks`? The column user_id doesn't exist on the Task because a task can be assigned to multiple Users

Comment: ahh, sorry, I forgot about the HABTM relation. Revising my answer

Comment: I updated my question with your code at the bottom, but slightly modified. Any idea why it's not returning anything at all? Your original code wasn't either.